# What do the numbers in brackets mean after City/Village on the RRT player aid card?

Tags: railroad-tycoon, railroad-tycoon-deluxe

The Railroad Tycoon player aid card shows the industries that produce certain goods, and the places that consume them.  However, after "Village" and "City" is sometimes a number in brackets:

[image: aid card]

What does the number mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The displayed number indicates the number of said building type you need to connect in order to buy the resource in question, when playing with the Advanced economy.

For example: In order to be able to transport Food to a City, you need to connect two cities to the food plant or Stockyard.

Another example: you won't get passenger traffic until you've connected 4 villages to your line if you only connect villages. With cities, a point-to-point connection will do.

Try searching for "Complex Economy", or check the Manual (pp. 39, 50, 76-79). Quoting it:

> The aggregate of supply and
> demand from several villages is needed to make rail service worthwhile